# Can you solve this? $15\cdot(3^{x+1}) - 243\cdot(5^{x - 2}) = 0$

Tags: exponential-function

This is an exponential functions problem. Please help me with this!

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried ?

Comment: I have tried multiplying 15 x 3 to get 45^x+1 and multiplying -243 x 5 to get -1215^x-2. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Will do you want to write $3^{x+1}$? in Mathjax this is `$3^{x+1}$`

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @Will: Notice that $15=3\cdot 5$ and $243=3^5$. Dividing by $3$ gives you $5\cdot 3^{x+1}=3^4\cdot 5^{x-2}$. From here finding $x$ is very easy

Answer (score 2):

There is no "nice" solution here (EDIT: referred to original question, not the edited one).

If you let $a = \log_3 5$ and $y = 3^x$, you can rewrite the equation as:

$15(y+1) - 243(y^a - 2) = 0 \implies 243y^a - 15y + 471 = 0$

but again there's nothing much you can do with that because $a$ is transcendental (but this form is a little more amenable to a numerical solution).

You can solve it approximately using numerical or graphical methods, and that would give you $x \approx 0.4803$.

EDIT: You have edited the question to be much more amenable to an elementary and exact solution.

If you meant $15\cdot(3^{x+1}) - 243\cdot(5^{x - 2}) = 0$, this is quite easily solvable.

Start by rearranging the equation to $15\cdot(3^{x+1}) = 243\cdot(5^{x - 2})$, then take logs of both sides. It doesn't matter which base you use, as long as you're consistent.

$\displaystyle \log 15 + (x+1)\log 3 = \log 243 + (x-2)\log 5$

Further rearrangement gives:

$\displaystyle x(\log 3 - \log 5) = \log 243 - 2 \log 5 - \log 15 - \log 3$

and the final solution is:

$\displaystyle x = \frac{\log 243 - 2 \log 5 - \log 15 - \log 3}{(\log 3 - \log 5)}$

I'll leave the final simplifications using basic log rules to you. You should get a very simple final answer.

Comment: $15\cdot 3^{x+1}=243\cdot5^{x-2}$ can be solved by taking $\log$s of both sides.

Comment: @anon The question was edited after I wrote my answer! I will edit my answer to account for this.